# .NET Core PartialAsync Exception after deployment

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i created a new .NET Core MVC application with the latest version of Visual Studio 2017. I then added a new view in my shared folder and reference it like this:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("MyNewView")
```

This works fine in development and on my local IIS.

Changing it to this (also copied the View in the specified folder):

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("../Account/MyNewView")
```

Gives me an exception like this:

> InvalidOperationException: The partial view '../Account/MyNewView' was not
>   found.

This one works only within Visual Studio but not on my IIS (File Deployment).

I guess this has something to do with precompiled views. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: use tilda : `"~/Account/MyNewView"`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the same exception even while debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are referenced by convention, so when you have something like `"MyNewView"` Razor translates that to `~/Views/[Controller]/MyNewView.cshtml`. If you have a view in a different directory than convention, you need to specify the full *project*-relative path, not just `Views` directory relative. In other words: `"~/Views/Accounts/MyNewView"`.

Razor will also search `Views/Shared` by convention, so if you have a view that you need to reference in multiple different controller view directories, it's best to place it there. Then, you can still just reference `"MyNewView"` regardless of what controller context you're in, and it will still work.

Comment: It works in my test application. But not in the real one :S But I will figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this, but maybe there is a better way (I like precompiled views):

I edited the csproj file and added this:

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

Here is the full csproj file for reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```